# What is wrong with this HTML5 <address> element?

Tags: css, firefox, html, stylesheet

```
<div id="header-container">
      <address>
        <ul>
            <li>lorem ipsum</li>
            <li>(xxx) xxx-xxxx</li>
        </ul>
    </address>
</div>
```

And the CSS looks like this:

```
#header-container address {float: right; margin-top: 25px;}
```

When I load the page, it looks fine in Chrome & IE, but in Firefox it's ignoring the styling completely. When I view source in firefox it looks like above, but in Firebug it looks like this:

```
<div id="header-container">
    <address> </address>
    <ul>
         <li>lorem ipsum</li>
         <li>(xxx) xxx-xxxx</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4457048/firefox-refusing-to-style-element-if-css-selector-contains-address-element

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**HTML5 is still a draft**. Firefox 3.6 doesn't completely support HTML5 yet.

And according to the [HTML4 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/struct/global.html#edef-ADDRESS), `address` can only contain `inline` elements:

```
<!ELEMENT ADDRESS - - (%inline;)* -- information on author -->
<!ATTLIST ADDRESS
  %attrs;                              -- %coreattrs, %i18n, %events --
  >
```

This is why Firefox considers it invalid and your page breaks.

Answer (score 0):

An unordered list cannot be wrapped inside of a address tag.  I checked using firebug and Firefox moves the close address tag before the unordered list.

Answer (score -1):

Add display block to CSS. And then, add the clear_both div before closing the address.
This will fix **any** problems with block elements inside an inline ones.

Your CSS:

```
#header-container address {display: block; float: right; margin-top: 25px;}
.clear { clear: both; }
```

HTML:

```
<div id="header-container">
  <address>
    <ul>
      <li>lorem ipsum</li>
      <li>(xxx) xxx-xxxx</li>
    </ul>
    <div class="clear"></div>
  </address>
</div>
```