# <address> element inside <p> lose display: inline property

Tags: html, css, inline

Without `<p>` like this all work well.

```
<footer>
  <a href="#">Text Here</a>
  <address style="display: inline"><a href="#">Text Here</a><address>
  <p>
    Text Here
  </p>
</footer>
```

But if add `<p>` then `<address>` element is getting displayed not inline. I need to make `<address>` acting inline. How to force that to be so?

http://fiddle.jshell.net/xKhYj/

```
<footer>
  <p>
    <a href="#">Text Here</a>
    <address style="display: inline"><a href="#">Text Here</a></address>
  </p>
  <p>
    Text Here
  </p>
</footer>
```

Comment: What are you seeing which leads you to believe the `address` is not inline? It's most likely the `p` element which is rendering as block, as it should.

Comment: http://fiddle.jshell.net/xKhYj/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works if u put inline to your `<p>` tag, too:

```
<p style="display:inline">
```

[Fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/PteZC/)

Comment: Yes, I tried that. But what with `<address>`? Why it loses display property? Is it a bug of this element?

Comment: The HTML standard says you can't have an `address` element inside a `p` element. `p` can only have "phrasing content", and `address` is not phrasing content: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Content_categories#Phrasing_content

Comment: So thank you. I think that is correct to change my mark up to `<p></p>` then `<address></address>` then `<p></p>`

Answer (score 2):

can you add `display:inline-block` or `display:block`

check the url

http://fiddle.jshell.net/PteZC/2/

Comment: can you add fiddle what you exactly want ?

Comment: I have http://fiddle.jshell.net/xKhYj/ Want to know why `<address>` element lose property when it's inside `<p>` tags.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4923072/what-is-wrong-with-this-html5-address-element check this out

Comment: else much more info about address tag i hope you will get your solution http://www.html5-tutorials.org/new-section-tags/address-tag/