# <address> tag loses its parent when assigned to "innerHTML" prop

Tags: javascript, html

[image]

Hi everyone,

can someone explain, why the  tag after inclusion in `innerHTML` prop of the `a` variable, loses its parent, which is the `<p>` tag at first place?

```js
var a= document.createElement("div");
   a.innerHTML = `<p data-le-dy-clone="20-1">saSA AsaS AKsjJKSA</p>
<p data-le-dy-clone="21-2">KASJAKSKAS kajsakjs saksjakkjas</p>
<p data-le-dy-clone="22-3">daaldlakd<address>daldklad</address>dlakldakldkl</p>
<p data-le-dy-clone="23-4">daldlakd daldakldk daldklaldad</p>`

console.log(a)
```

Comment: Can you add your JavaScript code to your question? Could be more helpful than a screendump.

Comment: Please add your code to the post as text, or rather as a runnable StackSnippet.

Comment: I updated the code with the one that I used, @Teemu

Comment: `<address>` is not allowed inside a `<p>` tag. Just like `<div>` is not allowed inside a `<p>` tag. The browser will interpret `</address>` as a mismatch to `<p>`, will close the previous P with `</p>` and `<address>` will reside being outside of any Paragraph element. https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dom.html#flow-content-2 and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Content_categories#phrasing_content

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan yes, I think the same :(

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12216753/address-element-inside-p-lose-display-inline-property