# What HTML5 tags should a three section footer contain use

Tags: html, semantic-markup

I am finding that the more semantic I make my HTML using the new HTML 5 tags the easier it is to style and work with the document. I am new to HTML 5 and only a HTML novice but I want to make my HTML 5 as semantically correct as possible. Currently I have my HTML 5 footer divided like so.

```
    <footer>
        <section>
            <h2>Contact</h2>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="snip">Email</a></li>
                <li><a href="snip">Tweet</a></li>
            </ul>
        </section>
        <section>
            <h2>Explore</h2>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="snip">Stack Overflow</a></li>
                <li><a href="snip">LinkedIn</a></li>
                <li><a href="snip">Flickr</a></li>
                <li><a href="snip">Google+</a></li>
            </ul>
        </section>
        <section>
            <h2>About</h2>
            <p>
               snip
            </p>
        </section>
    </footer>
```

The particular tags I am querying are section and use of the h2 tag. I would think section is more semantically correct that aside or article as each section of the footer is, well, a section. The h2 is also a concern to me. I would like to use H1 as it is the first heading in the section but I am afraid the google spider will shun me and keep me from making web friends if I use h1 over h2.

Thoughts from people who have worked with semantics are very much appreciated.

Comment: http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec-author-view/the-address-element.html#the-address-element could be intresting for you, if Google+ is meant to be the way to contact you. Maybe you snipped out an emaillink in the "about"-section ... I don't know.

Comment: The email and tweet parts are direct contact, the other is a link to my prospective pages rather than a way to contact me (although admittedly, they also have direct contact methods on them.)

Comment: okay, then see my answer below.

Comment: This is a useful tool to get an idea of outlining http://gsnedders.html5.org/outliner/.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may want to add the `address`-tag around your contact information:

```
<footer>
    <section>
        <h1>Contact</h1>
        <address>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="snip">Email</a></li>
                <li><a href="snip">Tweet</a></li>
            </ul>
        </address>
    </section>
    <section>
        <h1>Explore</h1>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="snip">Stack Overflow</a></li>
            <li><a href="snip">LinkedIn</a></li>
            <li><a href="snip">Flickr</a></li>
            <li><a href="snip">Google+</a></li>
        </ul>
    </section>
    <section>
        <h1>About</h1>
        <p>
           snip
        </p>
    </section>
</footer>
```

this would be semantically correct but watch out for older browsers which are having problems with the implementation of `<address>`. In Firefox 3.6.12 were no block-elements allowed to be placed inside `<address>` [like discussed here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4457048/firefox-refusing-to-style-element-if-css-selector-contains-address-element).

**EDIT:**
Also change the `<h2>` to `<h1>`:

> Notice how the use of section means that the author can use h1 elements throughout, without having to worry about whether a particular section is at the top level, the second level, the third level, and so on.

Comment: Any thoughts on the h1 and other uses of the section tag?

Comment: Note that this use of `address` would only be correct if there are no `article` elements on the page that are authored by someone else. If there are such `article` elements, you'd *have* to nest an additional `address` element in that `article` with the contact data of that author.